# Amazon EC2 Instance fails continuously, 1/2 status check

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am very new to AWS and EC2 instances. My EC2 instance fails every day or two and I have no clue why.
It says that 1/2 Status checks failed. I have tried to fix any errors (I don't believe there are) I have also changed ec2 instances. I created a totally new instance, and Still have the same problem. I can reboot, but it will fail the very next day.
If anyone could help I would really appreciate it!!!

EDIT:
For more context, I am running a few docker containers on the EC2 instance. The docker container is from The Things Network (https://www.thethingsindustries.com/docs/getting-started/installation/)
I followed the instructions exactly, and I have made sure there are no errors after the install.

The LOGS!!!:

```
Welcome to [1mUbuntu 20.04.2 LTS[0m!

[    2.776512] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <ip-172-31-1-239>.
[    3.149801] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice [0;1;39msystem-modprobe.slice[0m.
[    3.160582] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice [0;1;39msystem-serial\x2dgetty.slice[0m.
[    3.169747] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice [0;1;39mUser and Session Slice[0m.
[    3.178627] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mForward Password Râ€¦uests to Wall Directory Watch[0m.
[    3.189317] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Set up automount [0;1;39mArbitraryâ€¦s File System Automount Point[0m.
[    3.201144] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mUser and Group Name Lookups[0m.
[    3.210732] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSlices[0m.
[    3.218285] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSwap[0m.
[    3.225612] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mDevice-mapper event daemon FIFOs[0m.
[    3.235482] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mLVM2 poll daemon socket[0m.
[    3.245250] systemd[1]: Listening on multipathd control socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mmultipathd control socket[0m.
[    3.254695] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mSyslog Socket[0m.
[    3.262953] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mfsck to fsckd communication Socket[0m.
[    3.286765] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39minitctl Compatibility Named Pipe[0m.
[    3.297057] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mJournal Audit Socket[0m.
[    3.306158] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mJournal Socket (/dev/log)[0m.
[    3.321028] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mJournal Socket[0m.
[    3.329433] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mNetwork Service Netlink Socket[0m.
[    3.347160] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mudev Control Socket[0m.
[    3.368836] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mudev Kernel Socket[0m.
[    3.380182] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
         Mounting [0;1;39mHuge Pages File System[0m...
[    3.404172] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
         Mounting [0;1;39mPOSIX Message Queue File System[0m...
[    3.427061] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
         Mounting [0;1;39mKernel Debug File System[0m...
[    3.440263] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
         Mounting [0;1;39mKernel Trace File System[0m...
[    3.461084] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
         Starting [0;1;39mJournal Service[0m...
[    3.480157] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
         Starting [0;1;39mSet the console keyboard layout[0m...
[    3.499618] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate list of stâ€¦odes for the current kernel[0m...
[    3.537680] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
         Starting [0;1;39mMonitoring of LVMâ€¦meventd or progress polling[0m...
[    3.591571] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module drm[0m...
[    3.610351] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup being skipped.
[    3.637426] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[    3.655165] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
         Starting [0;1;39mFile System Check on Root Device[0m...
[    3.678285] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Modules[0m...
[    3.711172] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
         Starting [0;1;39mudev Coldplug all Devices[0m...
[    3.738158] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
         Starting [0;1;39mUncomplicated firewall[0m...
[    3.767401] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mJournal Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mHuge Pages File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mPOSIX Message Queue File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mKernel Debug File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mKernel Trace File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet the console keyboard layout[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate list of stâ€¦ nodes for the current kernel[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module drm[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mFile System Check on Root Device[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Modules[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mUncomplicated firewall[0m.
         Mounting [0;1;39mFUSE Control File System[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mKernel Configuration File System[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mFile System Check Daemon to report status[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mRemount Root and Kernel File Systems[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mApply Kernel Variables[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mudev Coldplug all Devices[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mFUSE Control File System[0m.
[    3.967715] EXT4-fs (xvda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mKernel Configuration File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRemount Root and Kernel File Systems[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mFlush Journal to Persistent Storage[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad/Save Random Seed[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate System Users[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mudev Wait for Complete Device Initialization[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mApply Kernel Variables[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad/Save Random Seed[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate System Users[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate Static Device Nodes in /dev[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate Static Device Nodes in /dev[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mudev Kernel Device Manager[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mudev Kernel Device Manager[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDispatch Password â€¦ts to Console Directory Watch[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLocal Encrypted Volumes[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mFlush Journal to Persistent Storage[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device [0;1;39m/dev/ttyS0[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mLoad/Save RF â€¦itch Status /dev/rfkill Watch[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mMonitoring of LVMâ€¦ dmeventd or progress polling[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mudev Wait for Complete Device Initialization[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mDevice-Mapper Multipath Device Controller[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDevice-Mapper Multipath Device Controller[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLocal File Systems (Pre)[0m.
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for amâ€¦on-ssm-agent, revision 3552[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for core18, revision 1997[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for lxd, revision 19647[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for lxd, revision 20326[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for snapd, revision 11588[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for snapd, revision 11841[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 3552[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for core18, revision 1997[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for lxd, revision 19647[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for lxd, revision 20326[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for snapd, revision 11588[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for snapd, revision 11841[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLocal File Systems[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor profiles[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSet console font and keymap[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate final runtâ€¦dir for shutdown pivot root[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mTell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate Volatile Files and Directories[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet console font and keymap[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate final runtâ€¦e dir for shutdown pivot root[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mTell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate Volatile Files and Directories[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Time Synchronization[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mUpdate UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mUpdate UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor profiles[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor proâ€¦managed internally by snapd[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mInitial cloud-init job (pre-networking)[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Time Synchronization[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Time Set[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Time Synchronized[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor proâ€¦s managed internally by snapd[0m.
[    6.469652] cloud-init[347]: Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 running 'init-local' at Thu, 13 May 2021 13:58:13 +0000. Up 6.05 seconds.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mInitial cloud-init job (pre-networking)[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork (Pre)[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Service[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Service[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mWait for Network to be Configured[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Name Resolution[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Name Resolution[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mHost and Network Name Lookups[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mWait for Network to be Configured[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mInitial cloud-iniâ€¦ (metadata service crawler)[0m...
[    8.673980] cloud-init[377]: Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 running 'init' at Thu, 13 May 2021 13:58:16 +0000. Up 8.54 seconds.
[    8.683098] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[    8.688504] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[    8.695309] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: | Device |  Up  |           Address           |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    |
[    8.702458] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[    8.710023] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |  eth0  | True |         172.31.1.239        | 255.255.240.0 | global | 0a:03:42:c0:e3:01 |
[    8.717534] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |  eth0  | True | fe80::803:42ff:fec0:e301/64 |       .       |  link  | 0a:03:42:c0:e3:01 |
[    8.724591] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |          127.0.0.1          |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |         .         |
[    8.732376] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |           ::1/128           |       .       |  host  |         .         |
[    8.746076] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[    8.753031] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route IPv4 info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[    8.758024] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[    8.763449] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: | Route | Destination |  Gateway   |     Genmask     | Interface | Flags |
[    8.768239] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[    8.774614] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |   0   |   0.0.0.0   | 172.31.0.1 |     0.0.0.0     |    eth0   |   UG  |
[    8.780157] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |   1   |  172.31.0.0 |  0.0.0.0   |  255.255.240.0  |    eth0   |   U   |
[    8.788509] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |   2   |  172.31.0.1 |  0.0.0.0   | 255.255.255.255 |    eth0   |   UH  |
[    8.799168] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[    8.804059] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++Route IPv6 info+++++++++++++++++++
[    8.809506] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[    8.813903] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway | Interface | Flags |
[    8.818267] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[    8.823267] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |   1   |  fe80::/64  |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
[    8.828363] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |   3   |    local    |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
[    8.832442] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: |   4   |  multicast  |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
[    8.836619] cloud-init[377]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mInitial cloud-iniâ€¦ob (metadata service crawler)[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mCloud-config availability[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork is Online[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Initialization[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mACPI Events Check[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily apt download activities[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily apt upgrade and clean activities[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mPeriodic ext4 Onliâ€¦ata Check for All Filesystems[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDiscard unused blocks once a week[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mRefresh fwupd metadata regularly[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily rotation of log files[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily man-db regeneration[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mMessage of the Day[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily Cleanup of Temporary Directories[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPaths[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mTimers[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mACPID Listen Socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mD-Bus System Message Bus Socket[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mDocker Socket for the API[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mOpen-iSCSI iscsid Socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mSocket unix for snap application lxd.daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mSocket activation for snappy daemon[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mUUID daemon activation socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mRemote File Systems (Pre)[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mRemote File Systems[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mAvailability of block devices[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mDocker Socket for the API[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mSocket activation for snappy daemon[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mAvailability of block devices[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSockets[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mBasic System[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mAccounts Service[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mACPI event daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mDeferred execution scheduler[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mcontainerd container runtime[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mRegular background program processing daemon[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mD-Bus System Message Bus[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSave initial kernel messages after boot[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mRemove Stale Onliâ€¦t4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mEC2 Instance Connect Host Key Harvesting[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLSB: Record successful boot for GRUB[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mirqbalance daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mDispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSystem Logging Service[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mService for snap aâ€¦on-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mService for snap application lxd.activate[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSnap Daemon[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLogin Service[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mPermit User Sessions[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDeferred execution scheduler[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRemove Stale Onliâ€¦ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mPermit User Sessions[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSystem Logging Service[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mHold until boot process finishes up[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mTerminate Plymouth Boot Screen[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mHold until boot process finishes up[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mTerminate Plymouth Boot Screen[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSerial Getty on ttyS0[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mSet console scheme[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet console scheme[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice [0;1;39msystem-getty.slice[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mGetty on tty1[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLogin Prompts[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: Record successful boot for GRUB[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mHostname Service[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mAuthorization Manager[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mAuthorization Manager[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mAccounts Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLogin Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUnattended Upgrades Shutdown[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mHostname Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mcontainerd container runtime[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mDocker Application Container Engine[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mEC2 Instance Connect Host Key Harvesting[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mOpenBSD Secure Shell server[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mOpenBSD Secure Shell server[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSnap Daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mWait until snapd is fully seeded[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mService for snap application lxd.activate[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mWait until snapd is fully seeded[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mApply the settings specified in cloud-config[0m...


Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ip-172-31-1-239 ttyS0

ip-172-31-1-239 login: [   15.446686] cloud-init[1324]: Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 running 'modules:config' at Thu, 13 May 2021 13:58:22 +0000. Up 15.01 seconds.
2021/05/13 13:58:25Z: Amazon SSM Agent v3.0.529.0 is running
2021/05/13 13:58:25Z: OsProductName: Ubuntu
2021/05/13 13:58:25Z: OsVersion: 20.04
[   19.928325] cloud-init[1591]: Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 13 May 2021 13:58:27 +0000. Up 19.72 seconds.
[   19.976274] cloud-init[1591]: Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 finished at Thu, 13 May 2021 13:58:27 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 19.91 seconds
```

Comment: It can only be what you're doing on the instance, and you haven't given us any details. Read this page, and add details if you'd like some help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html

Comment: @Tim I added context, I am just running a docker container

Comment: Still not near enough information to help. Go through the documentation I linked to, consider each of the things that makes up a status check, then look the AWS console to check which one you have broken.

Answer (score 1):

I would monitor several resources of your EC2 instance.

By default, you can only see CPU. If you install the [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html), you can collect additional metrics like RAM or Disk, which the hypervisor can't directly guess.

Then you can review the metrics around the time your instance fails, to check for some unexpected resource consumption.

I've had some issues in the past, where the lack of freeable RAM resulted in a similar behavior as the one you are describing.